# How to create a shell script to transfer file from a CD to documents?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, scripts

I want to transfer the folder from a CD to Documents in Ubuntu. How should i code it in shell? the folder name in the cd is CompFiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CD should be mounted in `/media/$USER/` directory, so the source directory becomes `/media/$USER/label_on_CD/CompFiles/` and your destination directory is `/home/$USER/Documents/`. To copy the files, either execute the command:

```
cp /media/$USER/label_on_CD/CompFiles/ /home/$USER/Documents/ -r
```

or write this command to a file and execute the command `bash file_name` where file_name is the name of the script.

Comment: how should i save this script? file_name.sh?

Comment: You can save it without `.sh` too. Bash interprets the file as a shell script even without it.